# Force dask to_parquet to write single file

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

When using `dask.to_parquet(df, filename)` a subfolder `filename` is created and several files are written to that folder, whereas `pandas.to_parquet(df, filename)` writes exactly one file.
Can I use dask's `to_parquet` (without using `compute()` to create a pandas df) to just write a single file?

Comment: Have you considered `.tar`-ing them up afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to a single file is very hard within a parallelism system. Sorry, such an option is not offered by Dask (nor probably any other parallel processing library).

You could in theory perform the operation with a non-trivial amount of work on your part: you would need to iterate through the partitions of your dataframe, write to the target file (which you keep open) and accumulate the output row-groups into the final metadata footer of the file. I would know how to go about this with fastparquet, but that library is not being much developed any more.

Comment: For parallelism, writing the columns in separate threads could at least in theory also be an option. But I do understand, Dask is just not made for this kind of parallelism.

Comment: Even then, each portion wouldn't know where in the file to seek to to start writing, until the earlier chunks were done

Comment: @mdurant can you please explain why `dd.to_parquet(filepath, partition_on="user")` produces parquet files with fairly similar sizes? In my dask dataframe, every partition is a parquet file and I am attempting to group by **user** and save each user data separately using `partition_on`. Now some users may have only 2 rows in the entire dask dataframe and some other users have thousands of rows. How does the `dd.to_parquet` work in this case, since the part.parquet files for all users are relatively equal in size? I am having an issue where the saved data is incomplete.

Comment: If you are losing data, you should make post code showing the process as a bug issue. When you partition_on, you get (up to) one file for each input partition X each unique value, there is no data grouping or shuffling.

Answer (score 4):

There is a reasons to have multiple files (in particular when a single big file doesn't fit in memory) but if you really need 1 only you could try this

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1_000,5))

df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=4)
df.repartition(npartitions=1).to_parquet("data")
```

Comment: This does somehow produce a file, but still it's creating a subfolder and not just a single file like pandas.to_parquet would do.

Comment: If it helps a little, the `.to_parquet` method in Dask 2.16.0 supports the parameter `write_metadata_file`. With `write_metadata_file=False`, `.to_parquet(...)` only produces `data/*.parquet` (without the two metadata files).

Comment: What is the consequence of not writing the metadata file? In terms of reading the files later down the line

Comment: @AmyChodorowski i didn't find any particular difference but maybe you should open a question so some developer could answer it.

Comment: @AmyChodorowski-still writes the parquet file in a sub-folder but without the metadata files.  The singular parquet file that was written looks good but the naming convention is "part.0.parquet".