# Dask dataframe concatenating parquet files throws out of memory

Tags: python, apache-spark, dask, pyarrow, dask-dataframe

I have 1024 parquet files, each 1mbin size. I'm using python `dask` to merge those 1024 files into a single file and I have a lot of disk space, but ram is some what limited.

Is there any efficient way to solve this using python `dask`?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
def generatePath():
    for i in range(0,1024):
         return "data/2000-" + i +".parquet"

def readDF():
    paths = generatePath()
    for x in paths:
       df = dd.read_parquet(x, columns=['name', 'address'], engine='pyarrow')
       yield df

def mergeDF():
    allDF = readDF()
    df = next(allDF)
    for iter_DF in allDF:
        df = dd.concat([df,iter_DF])
    return df.compute()
```

Here is my code and it throws out memory errors. Correct me if I am wrong under the hood. The code is loading file by file and creating each DF and then concatenating. In such case, it doesn't requires lot of memory?

Is there any other way to solve?

Comment: This question is about concatenating parquet files, using Dask, into a single parquet file - see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759297/dask-dataframe-concatenating-parquet-files-throws-out-of-memory#comment109267906_61774968).

Comment: your generate path funcion is returning instead of yielding

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**

To read and combine multiple files into a single `.parquet`, try `.repartition(1)` - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61109615/4057186) SO post

```
# Read all files in `data/`
df = dd.read_parquet("data/", columns=['name', 'address'], engine='pyarrow')

# Export to single `.parquet` file
df.repartition(npartitions=1).to_parquet("data/combined", write_metadata_file=False)
```

This will combine all the files in `data/` into a single file

```
$ ls data/combined
part.0.parquet
```

Note: There are benefits to using multiple parquet files - [1](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery), [2](https://aseigneurin.github.io/2017/03/14/incrementally-loaded-parquet-files.html), [3](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42918663/is-it-better-to-have-one-large-parquet-file-or-lots-of-smaller-parquet-files).

**Old answer**

There is no need to compute just to read the data. It will quickly fill up your RAM. This is likely causing your memory error. You can use `dd.read_parquet` and specify the `data/` folder directly

```
df = dd.read_parquet("data/", columns=['name', 'address'], engine='pyarrow')
```

Comment: .compute for every iteration is indentation mistake and I'm calling it once. my data is in multiple directories,just for the example i have added in that way.  Ultimate aim is to write that in single parquet file. Im thinking of trying to stream the data by limiting the size and ill try to right

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. IIUC, you want to combine all the files into a single `.parquet` file. See my updated answer.